# How to recover more detailed metrics in TensorFlow object detection library?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I use the [object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) library to train models on my own dataset given different hyper-parameters, pre-processing, etc.
Then I want to evaluate those models to compare them.

I know that the library have some evaluation mechanism, however it seems to return only *global* metrics. However when I will use my model, I will be able to discard some low confidence detections to match my need (prefer fn over fp).

So, is there a simple way to fetch the metrics like tp/fp/fn/precision/recall for each confidence threshold (instead of the AP) as well as for different IOU (0.1, 0.5, 0.75), to draw plots similar to [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval) ones.

If there is no simple way, can you give me some advices on how to implement new Evaluator/Evaluation classes to achieve this.

Thanks,
Alexis.

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented my own `object_detection.utils.object_detection_evaluation.DetectionEvaluator`. I give it lists of: categories, IOU thresholds, score thresolds, max number of detections and area ranges (for small, medium, big detections).

Then, it computes a confusion matrix for each combination of IOU, score, number of detections and area range, and aggregate it returning number of false/true positive/negative.

Kind